# Fixing cedar pocket hole failure

Tags: joinery, epoxy, adhesives

I built a cedar above ground planter last summer for my mother-in-law, and one of the sides didn’t hold well. I used pocket screws to secure the sides to the posts - but one broke out (pic below)...

To fix this, I was considering filling the void with some sort of adhesive and then simply placing the board back into place. Once the adhesive cures, it would be nice and solid. But I’m not sure what would work well(if at all).

What type of adhesive would work for that? Or is there a different approach that would work better?

Pic:

[image]

Comment: Did this failure occur just from the piece sitting there in the weather? Or was some specific stress put on this board? It's hard to visualise for certain, but it looks like this is a low-stress situation for the board in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like Loctite Marine Epoxy applied the way you described but also apply to the butt of the board.
My guess as to why the pocket hole failed, it appears the setup for the guide set the exit points too close to the edge of the butt on the side board and not at the butt's C/L.

Comment: Thanks - that sounds promising and will try that out.

Comment: OP, if you go ahead with a repair using epoxy it should be blended with filler(s) and not used straight. The most basic filler is fine wood dust. Although some smaller flakes/chips can be included and won't materially affect strength, generally a uniform fine dust is used (AKA "wood flour" if bought commercially, but many use the dust from the bag of a finish sander). And if you go with epoxy you should shop around for it..... in this application good enough is good enough. And the price differential between decent epoxies and those formulated for marine use can be quite substantial!